# Return values from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to return all the even and odd numbers in the turns column for this dataframe
This is what the data frame looks like

```
Turns victory_status   winner
13      out of time     white
10      resign          black
119     mate            white
8       outoftime       white
90      mate            black
```

I tried using

```
is_even = dd['turns'].astype(int) % 2 == 0
is_even.loc[is_even.turns == True , 'newcol'] = 0
```

But its not working out

Comment: So what output would you expect?

Comment: I would like just the even numbers in turns with their coressponding values in victory_staus and winner

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean masking to achieve this (if your 'Turns' column already contains numeric data, you can leave out the `astype(str)`)

```
df[df['Turns'].astype(int)%2==0]

    Turns   victory_status  winner
1   10      resign          black
3   8       outoftime       white
4   90      mate            black

df[~df['Turns'].astype(int)%2==0]

    Turns   victory_status  winner
0   13      outoftime       white
2   119     mate            white
```